# SQL query to fetch only rows if all values are equals to some value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have these two relations:

`alert`:

```
id    http_code_result  domain_id   ip_src

1          404              1         1.1.1.1
2          404              1         1.1.1.1
3          200              1         1.1.1.1
```

`domain`:

```
id    name
1     google
```

I want to get only the domains with 404 responses. So, for the IP address 1.1.1.1 it would return 0 rows, because the domain with id 1 also has one HTTP 200 response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your question is: "**You want to retrieve the domains having HTTP response 404. If the same domain is having responses other than 404 (Say 200), then that domain name should not be displayed.**"

Basing on this understanding, we can write query as follows::

```
SELECT d.id, d.name
FROM domain d, alert a
WHERE a.domain_id=d.id AND a.domain_id NOT IN(SELECT domain_id
                                              FROM alert
                                              WHERE http_code_result!=404);
```

Please Refer this **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/11f59/2)** link for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join to get your 404 alert and use a IS NULL in the WHERE clause to don't account for domain having a 404 alert.

```
SELECT domain.*
FROM domain LEFT JOIN alert ON domain_id = domain.id AND http_code_result = 404
WHERE alert.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect a query with a positive and a negative [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join this to be fastest, in particular if there can be multiple rows for either case.

```
SELECT *
FROM   domain d
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   alert
   WHERE  domain_id = d.id 
   AND    http_code_result = 404
   )
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   alert
   WHERE  domain_id = d.id 
   AND    http_code_result <> 404
   );
```

Your question is not completely clear on exact conditions.
A multicolumn index on `alert (id, http_code_result)` should be perfect for performance.

Or even the nested variant:

```
SELECT *
FROM   domain d
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   alert
   WHERE  domain_id = d.id 
   AND    http_code_result = 404
   AND    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   alert
      WHERE  domain_id = d.id 
      AND    http_code_result <> 404
      )
   )
```

Apply the more selective filter first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about the question, but when I'm right, you can fix this by using an aggregation:

```
SELECT
    domain.name,
    alert.ip_src
FROM    alert
    INNER JOIN domain ON alert.domain_id = domain.id
GROUP BY    -- create a group by name and ip:
    domain.name,
    alert.ip_src
HAVING  array_agg(http_code_result) @> ARRAY[404]   -- this group must have a 404
AND NOT array_agg(http_code_result) @> ARRAY[200];  -- this group may not have a 200
```

Maybe you don't want the ip address, than just leave it out.

Comment: Even PostgreSQL is my default RDBMS, I would like to have standard SQL as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.name from domain d, alert a where a.domain_id=d.id and domain_id not in(select domain_id from alert where http_code_result!=404);
```

This query will fetch all domains which have response codes other than 404, then exclude them from main data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name
from
    domain d
    inner join (
        select domain_id
        from alert
        group by domain_id
        having not bool_or(http_code_result <> 404)
    ) a on d.domain_id = a.id
```

The `not bool_or` was used in instead of the obvious `bool_and` below because it only needs to find one true row. The aggregation was done before joining for performance although in practice in this case probably there is no difference.

```
select domain_id
from alert
group by domain_id
having bool_and(http_code_result = 404)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
select domain_id, 
       count(http_code_result = 404 or null) as count_404, 
       count(http_code_result != 404 or null) as count_not_404
from alert a
where ip_src = '1.1.1.1'
group by domain_id
having count_404 > 0 and count_not_404 = 0;
```